# Purecss grids not working as expected

Tags: yui-pure-css

I am using the documentation at http://purecss.io/grids/
and basically copying the example code to create a grid of thirds

```
<div class="pure-u-1 pure-u-md-1-3"> ... </div>
<div class="pure-u-1 pure-u-md-1-3"> ... </div>
<div class="pure-u-1 pure-u-md-1-3"> ... </div>
```

However it is simply not displaying as the documentation explains - as 3 columns of equal thirds: http://jsfiddle.net/a7rnzn5f/1/

What am i not understanding ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's likely that you don't have the reference to the responsive part of the purecss grids.

From the link you provided:

> Since media queries cannot be over-written, we do not include the grid
>   system as part of pure.css. You'll have to pull it in as a separate
>   CSS file. You can do this by adding the following  tag to your
>   page.

```
<!--[if lte IE 8]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://yui.yahooapis.com/pure/0.6.0/grids-responsive-old-ie-min.css">
<![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://yui.yahooapis.com/pure/0.6.0/grids-responsive-min.css">
<!--<![endif]-->
```

Add that, and you should be good to go!

**EDIT:** I'm sorry, I didn't notice your fiddle. It looks like you did just the inverse. It doesn't look like you're including the base reference to purecss. [I updated your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a7rnzn5f/8/) with the reference below and it seems to work.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://yui.yahooapis.com/pure/0.6.0/pure-min.css">
```

Comment: is it just me or is this still broken?  the updated fiddle still doesn't render correctly, even when the external stylesheets are loaded in the correct order.  the only way I can get it to work is to remove the border...?

Comment: @simon you're not wrong. I think I got the wrong reference. Updated the fiddle link and it should be fine now.

Comment: This is not working. I believe you have to share the CDN for pure-css grid